# Spring Data JPA - case insensitive query w/ pattern matching

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Suppose I'm implementing search functionality for a simple CMS package (just an example), and want to match posts by both their `title` and `content`. Presumably, I would have some sort of `Post` entity with the following underlying table structure:

```
+------------------------------------+
|               POST                 |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
| post_id | INTEGER      | NOT NULL, |
| title   | VARCHAR(255) | NOT NULL, |
| content | CLOB         | NOT NULL  |
+---------+--------------+-----------+
```

Next, I would extend Spring's `JpaRepository` and add the search method via `@Query` annotation, like so (again, just an example):

```
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, Integer> {

    @Query("SELECT p FROM Post AS p WHERE lower(p.title) LIKE lower(%:searchTerm%)"  
            + " OR lower(p.content) LIKE lower(%:searchTerm%) ORDER BY p.title")
    List<Post> findBySearchTerm(@Param("searchTerm") String searchTerm);
}
```

The problem is that Spring (or maybe it's just the underlying JPA provider, not sure) has a hard time parsing this query due to the `lower(%:searchTerm%)` expression in the `WHERE` clause. I've also tried other variations of this syntax, *e.g.* `%lower(:searchTerm)%`, but none seem to work so far. Does anybody have a good (and preferably clean) solution for this?

*P.S.*: I would prefer to use the `@Query` annotation for consistency's sake. However, I guess other solutions (such as Spring's `method name -> query` derivation or the `Criteria API`) are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT u.username FROM User u WHERE u.username LIKE     
lower(CONCAT('%',:username,'%')"))
List<String> findUsersWithPartOfName(@Param("username") String username);
```

Notice: The table name in JPQL must start with a capital letter.

Comment: This answer seems to work, so thanks for that. However, you have not provided a fully working solution (I ended up using `lower(concat('%', :searchTerm, '%'))` instead). So for the sake of future readers -- refactor your answer to match the sample `Post` entity mentioned above and add the `lower()` functions around `concat()`. Then I will accept it.

Answer (score 4):

1) Inject `searchTerm` already in lower case to the method, and use JPQL `..... lower(COLUMN_NAME) like %:searchTerm%`

2) Use method names with following naming syntax, so you **don't need** to provide `%` to the JPQL `..... lower(COLUMN_NAME) :searchTerm`

```
findBySearchTermContainingIgnoreCase(String searchTerm)
findBySearchTermStartingWithIgnoreCase(String searchTerm)
```

Comment: These are both valid solutions that will undoubtedly be useful to someone. So thanks for pointing them out (I especially like the second one). However in this case, I am tempted to accept @Dale's solution since it's more in line with my current approach (`@Query` annotation).

Comment: These work with @Query. But did not mention specifically since you definitely want it.

Comment: Yeah, but I prefer not to mangle the repository method name in this case. The project that I'm working has really strict guidelines regarding this, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes. up to you. However `PostRepository` is a lower level API and normally  business logic goes to the business/service layer (Ex: with `@Service`) and your business names should go to the service/business interfaces unless you directly access the data layer objects from the top level. JPA repository provide these easy and simple interfaces Ex:`findByNNNContainingIgnoreCase` because it has nothing to do with the business needs.

Comment: Pushing the logic down into the repository level *IS* my intended goal. This is basic data access stuff, so the `Service` layer ought to know nothing about it (I don't want to have to use something like `findBySearchTermContainingIgnoreCase` from my service, while I could just call `findBySearchTerm`). This is why I don't really like the `method name -> query` derivation API in the first place. Also, as I mentioned -- this is just an example. The real query has to match against some other fields as well. This means that I would end up with a 100-character behemoth repository method name.